# PHP check website is reachable with or without www

Tags: php, web, url

In our website we have a form for our guests including a field for entering their website url. Some are entering their website url incorrectly like without www or adding www even if website is not reachable with www.

How can I make sure a website is accessible with or without www in PHP?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about `http://` and `https://`? Do some of your guests use those?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes, guests are entering the URL with https://. Only thing is some are entering website without www even their website is not reachable without www. Vise versa...

Comment: You'd need to check the http response header for 30x (redirect ) / 200 OK but this is not relyable as you would need to simulate a browser. Nowadays quite some websites are protected by cloudflare or similar tools to verify a human visitor and return a 403 to bots. Most simple solution imho is to place a nicely visible notice or to your visitors.